# NoReverseMatch at /^users/login/ (Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)

Tags: python, django

I set up a user registtation and authorization system to allow people to register an account and log in and out.
the first error is about TypeError: login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name', I fixed it ,but the second problem arises.like this:

```
NoReverseMatch at /^users/login/
Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/%5Eusers/login/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: D:\learning-note\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 668
Python Executable:  D:\learning-note\ll_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['D:\\learning-note',



Error during template rendering
In template D:\learning-note\learning_logs\templates\learning_logs\base.html, error at line 2

Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
1   <p>
2     <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
3     <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a> -
4     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
5       Hello, {{ user.username }}.
6     {% else %}
7       <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">log in</a>
8     {% endif %}
9   </p>
10  
11  
12
```

learning_log/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns =[
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls',namespace = 'learning_logs')),
]
```

learning_logs/base.html

```
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a> -
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Hello, {{ user.username }}.
  {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">log in</a>
  {% endif %}
</p>



{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

users/urls.py

```
  """defines URL patterns for users"""

    from django.conf.urls import re_path
    from django.contrib.auth import login
    from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

    from  . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        # login page
        re_path(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),
            name='login'),
    ]
    app_name = 'learning_logs'
```

users/login.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% if form.errors %}
  <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
  {% endif %}

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}

  <button name="submit">log in</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}" />
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no `index` view function in your `learning_logs` namespace which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: It is in `users` though

Answer (score 0):

You're using regex syntax for `path`. Either remove regex or use `re_path`:

```
 path('users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
```

or

```
 re_path(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
```